# Can't render data in EJS

Tags: node.js, database, render, ejs, psql

beginner programmer here.

I'm creating an app with node and express, and while I'm getting my h1 text and link to show up on the page, I can't seem to render data from the database I set up with pqsl. I haven't been able to find an answer that corresponds to what I'm doing, any help would be much appreciated!

here is the controller page:

```
const Goal = require('../models/goal');

const goalsController = {};

goalsController.index = (req, res) => {
  Goal.findAll()
  .then(goals => {
    res.render('goals/index', {goals: goals});
  })
  .catch(err => {
    res.status(400).json(err);
  });
};

module.exports = goalsController;
```

here's my goals/index.ejs page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Here's a look at all of your goals!!</h1>
  <a href="/goals/new">New Goal?</a>
  <div class="goal-container">
    <% goals.forEach(goal => { %>
      <h2>
      <a href="/goals/<%= goal.id %>"><%= goal.goal %></a>
      </h2>
    <% }) %>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

my routes page:

```
const express = require('express');
const goalsController = require('../controllers/goals-controllers');
const goalsRouter = express.Router();

goalsRouter.get('/', goalsController.index);

module.exports = goalsRouter;
```

and the model page:

```
const db = require('../db/config');

const Goal = {};

Goal.findAll = () => {
  return db.query('SELECT * FROM goals ORDER BY id ASC');
};

module.exports = Goal;
```

UPDATE: I've figured out that for some reason, my database is connected in psql but not my seed file. Haven't figured out the fix, but it's not an EJS problem after all!

Comment: As I understand, you can't see your `goals` on the page?
please, add some `console.log` statements to see if the problem is with EJS or querying the database. 
I suggest logging all the results after `findAll()` function in `then()` statement.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I've narrowed it down. The controller and routes are working, the problem seems to be in the EJS containing the .forEach on the index page. If I replace it with a snippet of text, it's fine, but when I put in the EJS nothing shows up!